# ¿Cómo leer el "Report I/O and transfer rate statistics" de sar en sysstat?

Tags: linux, io, sar, sysstat

**CONTEXTO.** Rhel 8.6, sysstat 11.7.3

**OBJETIVO.** Necesito obtener estadísticas legibles en kb, MB o GB, de los datos transferidos en banda ancha de sitio web.

**QUÉ ESTOY HACIENDO.** El servidor donde está hospedado el sitio web, tiene instalado sysstat y sus logs existen disponibles en /var/log/sa/. La [documentación sar](http://man.he.net/man1/sar) de sysstat menciona que la opción `-b` devuelve un "*Report I/O and transfer rate statistics*", y que muestra información de "*bread/s*". Los bread/s informan la "*Cantidad total de datos leídos de los dispositivos en bloques por segundo. Los bloques son equivalentes a sectores y por lo tanto tienen un tamaño de 512 bytes*".

Usé [Sarchart](https://sarchart.dotsuresh.com) para leer los datos del log de febrero, y me devuelve esta gráfica que no entiendo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sospecho que puedo lograr mi objetivo leyendo la información de los bread/s. El problema es que no entiendo dos cosas aquí:

1. ¿Qué significa exactamente "*Cantidad total de datos leídos de los dispositivos*"? ¿Ese total es el número de bytes que se han utilizado en banda ancha por la transferencia de datos?
2. Si el número promedio de la transferencia es 200 (como parece mostrar la gráfica), ¿significa que tengo que multiplicar 200 por 512 (bytes) para obtener el total de bytes transferidos?

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: `Blocks are equivalent to sectors and  therefore have a size of 512 bytes.` dice en la misma documentación que citas

Comment: Exacto, sí, eso dice. El problema es que no creo entender eso. Por eso formulé esta pregunta: Si el número promedio de la transferencia es 200 (como parece mostrar la gráfica), ¿significa que tengo que multiplicar 200 por 512 (bytes) para obtener el total de bytes transferidos? Muchas gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: Ajá. Cuando ese amigo hable de _blocks_, bloques, como en `bread/s` (bloques leídos sobre segundo), están pidiendo que asimiles bloques a fragmentos de 512B